# How to post json data from angular 2 application to local asp.net mvc webapi service?

Tags: sql-server

Actually am successful in getting data from local webapi service, but posting data not done yet.please suggest me is there any rules to post the data?.

Here, is my Customer.component.ts file code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomerService} from '../Services/Customer.service';
import { ICustomer } from '../Models/Customer';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
    selector:'customer-list',
    templateUrl:'app/Templates/Customer.component.html',
    styleUrls:['app/StyleSheet/Customer.Component.css'],
    providers:[CustomerService]
})

export class CustomerComponent
{
    customers : ICustomer[];
    result: number
    data: ICustomer;
    constructor(private _customerService : CustomerService){
    }

    postData():void{
       this.data =  {Id:1,Name:"hai",AadharNumber:784512235689,Address:"hai",PhoneNumber:7894561230};
       this._customerService.postData(this.data).subscribe(cust=>this.result = Number(cust));
    }
    ngOnInit():void{
       this._customerService.getAllCustomers().subscribe(cust=>this.customers=cust);
    }
}
```

Here, is my Customer.service.ts file code

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { ICustomer } from  '../Models/Customer';
import { Http,Response, RequestOptions, Headers} from '@angular/http' ;
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { JSONP_HOME } from '@angular/http/src/backends/browser_jsonp';

@Injectable()
export class CustomerService
{
    getserviceUrl : string="http://localhost:60769/api/Customer/AllCustomers";
    postServiceURL: string="http://localhost:60769/api/Customer/Insert";
    constructor(private _http:Http){}

   getAllCustomers(): Observable<ICustomer[]>{
       return this._http.get(this.getserviceUrl).map((response: Response)=><ICustomer[]> response.json());
   }
   postData(Customer:ICustomer): Observable<ICustomer>{
     var body = {"Id":"1","Name":"Hemarao","AadharNumber":"789456123012","Address":"SRIKAKULAM","PhoneNumber":"789456130"};
     let headers= new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
     let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
     var param = JSON.stringify(body);  

       return this._http.post(this.postServiceURL,param,options)
                .map((res: Response) => <ICustomer> res.json());
   }
}
```

Here, is my local webapi solution Customer.cs file code

```
public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public long AadharNumber { get; set; }
        public long PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

Here, is my local webapi solution CustomerApiController.cs file code

```
public class CustomerController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
       public List<Customer> AllCustomers()
        {
            return new List<Customer> { 
                new Customer { Id=101,Name="Murali Munna",AadharNumber=789456123012,Address="SRIKAKULAM", PhoneNumber=789456130},
                new Customer { Id=102,Name="Sivanagraj",AadharNumber=123045678956,Address="VIZIANAGARAM", PhoneNumber=1234567890},
                new Customer { Id=103,Name="Suresh",AadharNumber=123456789560,Address="VISAKHAPATNAM", PhoneNumber=8523697845},
                new Customer { Id=104,Name="Avinash",AadharNumber=85207410930,Address="EAST", PhoneNumber=5467891236},
                new Customer { Id=105,Name="SaiPrakash",AadharNumber=147852036956,Address="GUNTUR", PhoneNumber=7896541236}};
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public int Insert([FromBody]Customer customer)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public int Sample(string Name)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

Here, i have placed below code in web.config file

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:3000"></add>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, application/json"></add>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT, DELETE,OPTIONS"></add>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the rules is indeed allow certain https calls to have acces to the webapi, by configuring cors. I've temporarily allowed all calls to have acces to webapi as follow:

```cs
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(corsAttr);
```

Next and similar like you already did, is creating the webapi, something like this should work

```cs
        [ResponseType(typeof(CustomerDto))]
        public IHttpActionResult PostCustomer(CustomerDto Customer)
        {
            var _unitofwork = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer().Resolve<DalUnitOfWork>();
            var customer = ModelFactory.CreateCustomer(Customer);
            _unitofwork.CustomerRepo.Add(customer);
            _unitofwork.Commit();
            return Ok(new ClientMessage("Customer added.", string.Format("The customer {0} has been saved towards the database", Customer.Name), ClientMessageSeverity.success));
        }
```

To communicate with the server I prefer to work with the Httpclient and working with observables (perhaps a bit cleaner code). The code looks then like this

```cs
import { Component, ViewChild, Input, OnInit, Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { URLSearchParams, QueryEncoder,Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class CustomerserviceService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient,private httpold: Http, private notificationService: NotificationsService, private databaseservice: DatabaseServiceIsbusy) {       
    }

    private baseUrlTask = 'http://localhost:45258/customer'

    private httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({ 
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        })
      };

     public addCustomer(customer: ICustomer):Observable<IClientmessage>{
        return this.http.post<IClientmessage>(this.baseUrlTask, customer,this.httpOptions).catch(error =>this.handleError(error));;
    }
```